# How to validate by default a parameter in a laravel api route

Tags: php, laravel, api, validation, routes

A question has arisen.
Suppose I have an api route that is

```
get: api/v1/conferences/{conference_id}/languages
```

The purpose would be to get the languages linked to this conference.
My program, almost always starts with `conferences/{conference_id}` so the conference_id must always be real. In case the `conference_id` does not exist, I should throw an exception.

I want to do this without putting any logic in the controllers or any class that has any particular logic of mine. I would like it to be validated by default from the laravel kernel, is that possible?

I mean, i want that every time somebody access to a route which starts with `conferences/{conference_id}` the program would be able to check if this id is real

Thanks

Comment: Does conference has a model ?

Comment: [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) should do the work for you. Have you tried it?

Comment: You should check explicit route binding: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#explicit-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exists in validation rules like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ConferencesRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function all($keys = null)
    {
        $data = parent::all();
        $data['conference_id'] = $this->route('conference_id');

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'conference_id' => ['required', 'integer',  'exists:' . App\Models\Conference::class . ',id'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Or, if you dont want to use a FormRequest class, use this:

p.s. param should be changed to conference instead of conference_id:

```
use App\Models\Conference;
 
Route::get('conferences/{conference}/languages', function (Conference $conference) {
    //...
});
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding